# Как решается баг с slick-slider с переключением последнего слайда на первый?

Tags: html, css, slider-slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этом гиф можно увидеть как выглядит баг.

HTML

```
<section class="proff">
        <div class="container slider__container">
            <h2 class="proff__title title">
                Our professionals
            </h2>

            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <div class="photo__card">
                        <div class="slide__image">
                            <img class="slide__img" src="images/man-1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide__text">
                            <h4 class="name__text">David Robertson</h4>
                            <p class="info__text">photographer with 5 years of experience</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <div class="photo__card">
                        <div class="slide__image">
                            <img class="slide__img" src="images/man-2.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide__text">
                            <h4 class="name__text">Joey Tribbiani</h4>
                            <p class="info__text">photographer for over 6 years</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <div class="photo__card">
                        <div class="slide__image">
                            <img class="slide__img" src="images/man-1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide__text">
                            <h4 class="name__text">David Robertson</h4>
                            <p class="info__text">photographer with 5 years of experience</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider__item">
                    <div class="photo__card">
                        <div class="slide__image">
                            <img class="slide__img" src="images/man-2.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide__text">
                            <h4 class="name__text">Joey Tribbiani</h4>
                            <p class="info__text">photographer for over 6 years</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                

            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

Детальнее можно посмотреть в кодпен https://codepen.io/Loremord/pen/eYQMbJm